# SSH session closed when BASH script terminated (quite NON-standard case)

Tags: ssh

I start ssh session from a BASH script. So, NO console is involved at all. (This is needed for reverse-SSH).

I need the SSH session:

1. To keep alive after the script is finished;
2. To terminate it from another script (under some conditions of course);

Was thinking about virtual terminal session (using cat probably...), but have no idea how-to OR may be there's another "right" way to do it.

TNX (in advance)!

Comment: If you share why you need "reverse-SSH", you might find there is an easier way to meet your use case than the approach you are trying to get to work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying to maintain an SSH tunnel.
There are many ways to do it, I don't know if there is a "right" one though, as it depends heavily on what are you actually trying to achieve.

One approach (one of the easier ones) is to start the SSH session in a screen, give it a unique name, and use screen's commands to terminate it. Here is a sample script which does that:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                 

SCREENNAME="the_great_ssh_tunnel"
SSHCOMMAND="ssh -N -R ...."                                     

case "$1" in                                                                
  start)                                                                    
    if screen -ls|grep -q "$SCREENNAME"; then                               
      echo "Already running."                                               
    else                                                                    
      screen -m -d -S "$SCREENNAME" $SSHCOMMAND                             
      echo "Started."                                                       
    fi                                                                      
    ;;                                                                      
  stop)                                                                     
    if screen -ls|grep -q "$SCREENNAME"; then                               
      echo "Stopping"                                                       
      screen -S "$SCREENNAME" -X kill                                       
    else                                                                    
      echo "Not running"                                                    
    fi                                                                      
    ;;                                                                      

  isrunning)                                                                
    if screen -ls|grep -q "$SCREENNAME"; then                               
      echo "Running."                                                       
    else                                                                    
      echo "Not running."                                                   
    fi                                                                      
    ;;                                                                      

esac
```

If you have root access, you might want to convert this to a systemd unit.